# Is there a LINQ equivalent for this code?

Tags: c#, linq

I am absolute beginner at LINQ.

Can code for `GetAnimals<T>()` be written in LINQ?

```
ObservableCollection<Animal> allAnimals = new ObservableCollection<Animal>();

public IEnumerable<T> GetAnimals<T>() where T: Animal
{
    foreach (var animal in allAnimals)
        if (animal.GetType() == typeof(T))
            yield return (T)animal;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want [Enumerable.OfType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx):

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetAnimals<T>() where T: Animal
{
    return allAnimals.OfType<T>();
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it - although it does seem a little much to push it out to a new method

Comment: @Chris, the new method would give it the extra constraint where T : Animal. It might be a good idea.

Comment: I remember why I made it a method now - allAnimals is private, this is an accessor method.

Answer (score 4):

There's already an extension method for this: [`OfType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx)